# Unparseable date at offset 0)

Tags: android, parsing, date, simpledateformat

I keep getting this exception and i don`t know what could be wrong.
Can somebody pls help me?
Below code is to parse the items (Date/timestamp) and then show them in a listview.
I know they are strings but they need to be added in a listview.

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "9 minutes ago" (at offset 0)
```

---

```
public static String formatDate(final long dt) {
    return formatDate(new Date(dt));
}

public static String formatDate(final Date date) {
    final DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT,
            DateFormat.SHORT);
    return df.format(date);
}

public static final Date parseDate(final String date) throws ParseException {
    final String pattern = "EEE MMM dd, yyyy h:mm a";
    return parseDate(date, pattern);
}

public static final Date parseDate(final String date, final String pattern)
        throws ParseException {
    final SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern, Locale.US);
    return format.parse(date);
}
```

---

Code to add the items in Listview:

```
private String getDateString(final Date d) {
    if (d == null)
        return "";

    int[] elements1, elements2;

    elements1 = getDateElements(System.currentTimeMillis());
    elements2 = getDateElements(d.getTime());

    if (elements1[0] == elements2[0] && elements1[1] == elements2[1]) {
        if (elements1[2] == elements2[2])
            return "Today";

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
        elements1 = getDateElements(c.getTimeInMillis());

        if (elements1[2] == elements2[2])
            return "Yesterday";

    }
    return Util.formatDate(d);
}

private int[] getDateElements(final long d) {
    final int[] elements = new int[3];
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTimeInMillis(d);
    elements[0] = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    elements[1] = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    elements[2] = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    return elements;
}
```

Comment: The string "9 minutes ago" cannot be parsed as a date time. You can't do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error message you are having is quite clear "9 minutes ago" string cannot be parsed as date time.

- [Java Date/Time parsing and formatting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/format.html)
- [Predefined Date/Time formatters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#predefined)

You will need additional code to be able to parse date/time in such format.

You can try with [Natty Date Parser](http://natty.joestelmach.com/)